# Spring Maven reading from resources folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, classpath

I'm using Spring Boot. I want to read a json file in src/main/resources folder.

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(inputFileName).getFile());
```

Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Now, when I run my Spring Boot application in Eclipse using Spring Tools (Run As -> Spring Boot App), I get NoSuchFileException and the application is trying to find the file in /target/classes/ instead of /src/main/resources folder.

Also, I cannot see the file in /target/classes/ folder. Why isn't maven copying it to target/classes?

What can I do to read from the resources folder?

Comment: Stop using file IO to read classpath resources. Classpath resources, at runtime, are **not** on the file system, but bundled inside jar files. Just use getResourceAsStream(), and you'll have an InputStream that you an read from. You don't need a File.

Comment: In Eclipse, select the spring boot project, press ALT+F5 and then press ok. Try to run as Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1):

if you are work in a normal maven java project. `src/main/resources` are in the class path by default. So you are fine to access the files under it when you package with maven. Even if in Eclipse project, file in `resources` will be copied to `target/classes` folder. So no problem.

Comment: But the resources are not getting copied to target/classes folder. When are they copied?

Comment: once project is built. Copy will happen.

Comment: the folder should be resources, not resource, per https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use file to read the contents. You can just call

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(inputFileName)
```

This way it will work whether you have JAR/WAR file or running it in eclipse. As Yuan pointed out, resources will get copied and bundled in the files after the build. Eclipse manages the maven classpath and will add appropriate entries to classpath when application is executed.